# Apache Spark S3 Error

Tags: hadoop, amazon-s3, apache-spark, bigdata, spark-streaming

I am trying to connect `amazon s3` to `Sparkstreaming`. I am running code on my local machine and trying to stream from s3 to Spark and I got below error:

> java.io.IOException: No FileSystem for scheme: s3n

Can you please help me in solving the same?

Answer (score 3):

You can solve it by specifying the implementation of s3n scheme in the hadoop configuration of your spark context:

```
sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.NativeS3FileSystem")
```

In order to access s3 you may also need to specify AWS credentials:

```
sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3n.awsAccessKeyId", "***")
sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3n.awsSecretAccessKey", "***")
```

Then you can create your StreamingContext in the following way:

```
val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, Seconds(1))
```

You may want to try accessing s3 through s3a:// instead of s3n:// which uses aws-sdk library instead of jets3t to access the files.